# highlight word in vim with an outline

Tags: vim, highlight

I have a small snippet of VimScript that highlights certain words in Vim.

But I can't seem to find what is the right highlight group to use to have something that outlines the word (vs. a "normal" highlight that looks like a text selection).

Here are a few variations I've tried. This one with `TabLineFill`:

```
    exe printf('match TabLineFill /\<%s\>/', g:word)
```

And this one with `IncSearch`:

```
exe printf('match IncSearch /\<%s\>/', g:word)
```

[image: outline highlight with Sublime Text]

Comment: AFAIK this is not part of the ANSI standard and no terminal emulator I know has this kind of feature. I think you're trying to replicate functionality of a graphical text editor in a command-line editor.

Comment: I am OK if this doesn't work in a Terminal Emulator and just on a graphical version of Vim (gvim, macvim, etc...)

Comment: In GVim/MacVim, the GUI is only a glorified terminal emulator. You will need to hack the GUI part of the source code to reach your goal. Good luck with that.

Comment: I concur with the previous commenters: this is simply impossible in Vim. Sorry :-( The closest is underline or undercurl (gVim only).